# Why does my client send request so slowly?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, performance

I have WCF client to send request to a service. And my business code call the client API to send 300+ requests per second. But my client only sends about 50 to service according to te performance counters of my service and WCF ServicePoint.

And I have increased ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to 1000 in code, and setted maxConCurrentCalls to 1000 in service configuration file but got little improvement.

I guess there might be queue in WCF client for requests to send. Is there any way to configure it and speed up my client.

Here is my configuration for client:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: A simple test would be to start two concurrent clients and see if they produce hits at twice the rate on the server. If they do, it is a client throttling issue.

Comment: I have found the reason. There is a thread limitation(50) defined by IIS 6.0. A solution for this problem is host my service with a customized host.

Answer (score 1):

You may be hitting the connection limit for out going http connections:

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
     <add address="*" maxconnection="8"/>
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Note the default value is 2.

Comment: Is it the same as  ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit? I have updated it to 1000 in code.

Comment: I do not think that it is the same. Try putting the above configuration in the config file of your wcf client.

Comment: <add address="*" maxconnection="8"> sets ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to 8 (in my .NET 4 app anyway), so they appear to be the same.